# How to execute one line in the .emacs file?

Tags: functions

To test a function definition, for example :

```
(defun count-words-buffer ()
  (let ((count 0))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (< (point) (point-max))
      (forward-word 1)
      (setq count (1+ count)))
    (message "buffer contains %d words." count)))
```

The goal would be to test a function while writing, without restarting Emacs.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking how you run the function?

Comment: To call the function you use `(count-words-buffer)`.  To debug it you use `M-x debug-on-entry count-words-buffer` and then call it.

Comment: @Dan the goal of the question is added

Comment: @Drew cool ! Thanks for the debug-on-entry tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've just typed or modified the function and you want to (re)define it, press `C-M-x` ([`eval-defun`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html)) with the cursor anywhere in the definition.

To run the function, use `M-:` ([`eval-expression`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html)) and type `(count-words-buffer)` then `RET`. If the function needed arguments, you'd need to add them after the function name, e.g. `(my-function "first argument" 'second-argument)`.

Alternatively, go to the [`*scratch*` buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Interaction.html#Lisp-Interaction) and type your code (e.g. `(count-word-buffers)`). You can either use `C-M-x` or press `C-j` at the end of a line to execute that line of code (or more precisely, the Lisp expression that ends at the cursor). `C-j` additionally inserts the return value into the buffer. This only lets you execute the function in the `*scratch*` buffer, you need to use the `M-:` method to run it from another buffer.

---

The way you've defined the function, it isn't a [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html#Defining-Commands) that can be called interactively. To make it one, add an [interactive specification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html#Using-Interactive) to the function definition.

```el
(defun count-words-buffer ()
  (interactive "@")
  …)
```

Then you can run the command with `M-x count-words-buffer RET`, you can bind it to a key, etc.

To be able to use the function from Elisp as well, it should return the number of words rather than print it as a message. You can either make a non-interactive function for lisp use and a separate command that just calls the non-interactive function and calls `message` on the result, or combine the two and just omit the `message` call if the function is not [called interactively](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Distinguish-Interactive.html#index-called_002dinteractively_002dp-1641).

```el
(defun count-words-buffer ()
  (interactive "@")
  (let ((count 0))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (< (point) (point-max))
      (forward-word 1)
      (setq count (1+ count)))
    (if (called-interactively-p)
        (message "buffer contains %d words." count)
      count))
```

---

This function already exists in Emacs, with the added bonus that if the region is active, it counts the words in the region. It's called (unsurprisingly) [`count-words`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Position-Info.html#Position-Info) and you can [look at how it's coded](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26.3/lisp/simple.el#L1204).

Comment: Great... Many thanks !

Comment: Could you clarify what's the use of "@" in the `interactive` here? (I've looked at the docstring).

Comment: @JeanPierre If you bind this command to a mouse click, it'll activate the window that you click on.